# Solve Equation with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, nonlinear

I am trying to solve nonlinear equation in mathematica, the equation include the function Erfc which is defined in mathematica, the equation is true and I should for sure get answer. but for some reason It doesn't stop running though it should take a few seconds, and I think that there is a syntax problem , I try hard to find it but couldn't so please help me find the problem.

```
BR = 0.0001;
xvec = {1.8};
y = -100;
bindEVSa = 
Table[{xvec[[b]], 
qdim /. NSolve[{ (qdim  N[Erfc[qdim BR]])/(
     qdim/y Exp[qdim^2 BR^2] *N[Erfc[qdim BR]] - 1) - qdim^2 + 1/(
     1/xvec[[b]] - 1/y) == 0, qdim >= 0}, {qdim}, 
  Reals][[1]]}, {b, Length[xvec]}]
(*or*)
bindEVSa = 
Table[{xvec[[b]], 
qdim /. NSolve[{ (qdim  N[Erfc[qdim BR]])/(
     qdim/y Exp[qdim^2 BR^2] *N[Erfc[qdim BR]] - 1) - qdim^2 + 1/(
     1/xvec[[b]] - 1/y) == 0, qdim >= 0}, {qdim}][[1]]}, {b, 
Length[xvec]}]
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work for your actual problem, but `bindEVSa=Table[{xvec[[b]],qdim/. FindRoot[qdim N[Erfc[qdim BR]]/(qdim/y Exp[qdim^2 BR^2]*N[Erfc[qdim BR]]-1)-qdim^2+1/(1/xvec[[b]]-1/y)==0,{qdim,1}]},{b,Length[xvec]}]` returns the solution in 0.001 seconds

Comment: thank you very much ! , it gives the right answer! but did you know why Nsolve doesn't work ?

Comment: Your `NSolve` was complicated enough that I was not able to quickly find exactly what was causing the problem for you so I got the answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

From the documentation, "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations." For other equations, `NSolve` **may** be helped by adding constraints to simplify the search. In this case, constrain `qdim` to an interval, e.g., `5 > qdim >= 0`, rather than just restricting it to be nonnegative.

```
BR = 0.0001;
xvec = Range[1.8, 10.8, 1.8];
y = -100;

bindEVSa = 
 Table[{xvec[[b]], 
   NSolveValues[{(qdim Erfc[qdim BR])/(qdim/y Exp[qdim^2 BR^2]*
            Erfc[qdim BR] - 1) - qdim^2 + 1/(1/xvec[[b]] - 1/y) == 0, 
      5 > qdim >= 0}, qdim, Reals][[1]]}, {b, Length[xvec]}]

(* {{1.8, 0.923629}, {3.6, 1.43531}, {5.4, 1.82517}, 
    {7.2, 2.14803}, {9., 2.4266}, {10.8, 2.67296}} *)
```